# Test for Look-ahead bias in Time Series Forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, bias

I have a general question regarding testing for look-ahead bias. Is there any technical test for look-ahead bias in training data? Especially in the context of time series forecasting e.g. predicting future price returns? All I can think of is checking for lead-lag correlation for each feature against the test set? But how many period of lags should I be testing? What if the feature is not stationary but a random walk process, which means the current X_t will always correlate with X_{t+1}?

Many thanks